# Stored Procedure List Run Time Conversion

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.5

Inside My '`MyOtherViewModel`' I have the below code that is

Throwing Error: `Argument Type myStoredProcedure not Assignable to parameter type MyDbTable`

It is throwing @ `(this, c)` Compile Time Error

```
var query = myWCFClient.myStoredProcedure();
//Some Other Stuff                                          
query.ToList().ForEach(c => myCollection.Add(new MyViewModel(this, c)));
```

Inside `MyViewModel` I have :

```
public MyViewModel(MyOtherViewModel owner, MyDbTable table)
       :base(owner, "String")
{
        //other stuff
}
```

Then I try

```
var t = ((IEnumerable)query).Cast<MyDbTable>().ToList();
t.ToList().ForEach(c => mCollection.Add(new MyViewModel(this, c)));
```

And Get: `Unable to cast object of type 'myStoredProcedure' to type 'MyDbTable'.` Run Time Error

What is the best way to handle this in `VS 2012`, `c#` `.Net 4.5` using WCF.

Procedure is `myStoredProcedure[]`  and this is returning a count of 0

```
var t = query.OfType<MyDbTable>().ToList();
```

Comment: Are MyOtherViewModel, MyDbTable etc real class names? If so, you shoudl realy consider renaming them to meaningful names. Boy, will your code improve!

Comment: No they are not real names, that is how I typed them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first piece of code you are putting objects of type `myStoredProcedure` in the constructor of `MyViewModel` while that constructor expects an object of type `MyDbTable`. That's why you get a compile time error on that piece of code.

The second piece of code you try to cast the `myStoredProcedure` to a `MyDbTable`. That's why you get a run time exception on that piece of code.

Your WCF-service is returning other objects than you expect. Investigate the service or change the constructor of `MyViewModel` to accept objects of class `myStoredProcedure`.